# Tracking multiple installations with google analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I have a web based application, which is installed at several clients already. I want to get som einsight how the application is used at these clients. I have their consent on this, but I can't figure out how to collect all tracking data from the installations via Google Analytics. These installations are on different domains, some of the are on intranets. I'm not the owner of those domains, however I would like to collect the data under one GA property-id to have the merged behavior. I would like to be bale to see separate data too for each installations if possible.
But is this possible somehow?

Comment: This is possible via the hostname field (via view filters, report filters, or segments). Since this is mostly a reporting question (as opposed to a programming question) this might be off-topic for stackoverflow.

Comment: Just use the same GA code in all cases and (as Eike says) filter on hostname - works a treat.